# Wrong choice of Computer/Project when doing Windows-P

Tags: windows-7, windows, display

Win-P brings up the "choose display" dialog, allowing you to choose which monitors your computer will use. For some reason, the main screen was chosen as "project" (or 2), and my larger screen, which is usually off, was chosen as "Computer" (or main, 1).

How do I make my main computer screen number one?

Answer (score 3):

Two things to try.

#### 1:

Power down the machine and swap the monitor leads as they plug in to the computer, this may work to swap the monitors around.

#### 2:

Right click on your Desktop and select "Screen Resolution" as below.

[image]

Then you should have a screen like this:

[image]

You should be able to simply select the monitor you want to be the main one, click "Make this my main display" and click "Apply"

After that the "Computer" monitor should be the main one.